# native2ascii doesn't honour surrogate pairs

Tags: java, unicode, surrogate-pairs

For some reason, `native2ascii` ignores surrogate pairs when re-encoding escaped characters (`\u????`) back to Unicode:

```
$ echo '\ud834\udd1e' | native2ascii -reverse -encoding UTF-16BE | hexdump -C
00000000  00 5c 00 75 00 64 00 38  00 33 00 34 00 5c 00 75  |.\.u.d.8.3.4.\.u|
00000010  00 64 00 64 00 31 00 65  00 0a                    |.d.d.1.e..|
0000001a
```

Is this the intended behaviour?